# How to access the value of the dynamically created element in AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have to add multiple HBoxw  dynamically  which contains the following set of components...

I'm trying to access the value of each dynamically created element?How to do?

```
                            var myHBox:HBox=new HBox();             

            var txt1:ComboBox=new ComboBox();
            var txt2:TextInput=new TextInput();
            var txt3:TextInput=new TextInput();
            var txt4:TextInput=new TextInput();
            var txt5:TextInput=new TextInput();
            var txt6:TextInput=new TextInput();
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Could you add any code that you tried but failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link,It will help to you..

[Adobe containers intro](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_6.html)

Answer (score 1):

the normal RTTI order would be parentName.parentName.(and so on and on).objectName
but in the case you are already having the object names, there is no need of complex RTTI access.

If this is just an example, I would suggest you to use a object which is responsible for storing your objects, and later to access them easy. - Object like HashMap or Dictionary or even something less complex at the first place like Vector arrays or so.